# How can I post multipart image without to save on disk?

Tags: go

I need to download an image and upload it on another service. Is it possible to upload it without to save it on disk ? I checked the [go docs](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) but I couldn't find any straightforward method not even to upload/post multi part from disk. 
So far I have this non-working code

```
func upf(file []byte) (url string, err error) {

    URL := "http:///max.com/upimg"
    b := bytes.Buffer
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(b)

    part, err := writer.CreateFormField(file)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return http.NewRequest("POST", URL, b)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
response, error := http.Get("http://another.service.com/image.jpg")

if error != nil {
    // handle error
}

_, error = http.Post("http://max.com/upimg", "image/jpg", response.Body)

if error != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

If you need to post multipart you'll have to encode the response's Body;

```
buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

encoder := multipart.NewWriter(buffer)

field, error := encoder.CreateFormField("image") // Set "image" to correct field name

if error != nil {
    // handle error
}

_, error = io.Copy(field, response.Body) 

if error != nil {
    // handle error
}

// and then Post buffer instead of response.Body
```

Remember to set the correct `Content-Type` header in your POST request (e.g. http.Post's second argument) to something like:

```
"multipart/form-data; boundary=" + encoder.Boundary()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: multiple-value encoder.CreateFormField() in single-value context

Comment: yeah my code had a bug (edited) but please, don't copy paste code off the internet. Look at it as a guideline; try to understand the code.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code but it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat, the idea is that `response.Body` is *something* implementing the `io.ReadClose` interface -- that is, you are able to repeatedly call `Read()` on it, until it signals `EOF` (at which `Close()` is called automatically).

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat, The `http.Client`'s `Post()` method takes an instance of `io.Reader` -- the interface the `Body` member of the HTTP response object also satisfies (`io.ReadCloser` is `io.Reader` + `io.Closer`), so you can just pass the GET reponse's `Body` as the POST's body argument and see the magic happen: the code performing HTTP POST will use the object representing the body of the HTTP GET response to get data for posting--by repeatedly calling `Read()` on it hence draining data from the download server and sending it to the upload server.  This happens all by itself.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat, in the second, multi-part, example this can't be made to work *that* simple because you can't just have Go shovel your data between the response and request objects as you have to *construct* the request body dynamically.  So the example uses `io.Copy` to pipe the data from the HTTP GET's response `Body` to the body of a particular part of the multi-part payload of the request object you're generating.  There again, the `multipart.Writer` object returned by `CreateFormField()` works in the same way as the response writer object from `net/http`, so the idea is the same.